# How do I Gain weight?

Tags: diet, weight-gain

I am 19 my weight is 54 kg and height is 5'11. I am an skinny or you can say and ectomorph. 
I am an ovo lacto vegetarian. I hit gym every alternate days but I didn't gain any weights so please suggest me how do i gain weight what should i add to my diet

Comment: Meat would be a good start.

Comment: Just increase your overall caloric intake, it seems to me that you don't eat enough for your height and the amount of exercise you're participating in. First of all find your Basic Metabolic Rate (search for it on Google), then keep on eating until you surpass it. Plus there is really no such thing as different somatotypes (i.e. ectomorph, endomorph, mesomorph). People are just too complex to confine them into three categories.

Comment: @Tarius: TDEE is a more useful metric to use since it takes physical activity into account. One can eat above their BMR yet still be under their TDEE which will still result in weight-loss.

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant, just wasn't sure on the terminology. Usually sites which calculate your BMR include an option for the amount of physical exercise you perform as well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Doughnuts. Eat a lot of them. They're vegetarian, delicious, and very fattening. And stop going to gym, it's making you lose weight. Just sit on the couch and watch TV all day.-satire

Answer (score -1):

you can eat Much Carb and Meat. For Gain mass you can Dring Mass Gainer Milk.

If you focus gain weight, 1st you must eat much.